# The units in some extensions of integers

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

What are the units in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[a]$, where $a$ is the n-th root of unity in the complex field $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: [Cyclotomic units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_unit)

Comment: I did not find the answer through the link... It talks about fields not rings!!

Comment: Dear @Katy: the terminology in algebraic number theory is that when one talks of the group of units for a particular number field $K$, one really means the group of units (=invertible elements) in the ring of algebraic integers in $K$. (Of course, in any field, every non-zero element is a unit; so looking at the Wikipedia page one might guess that "unit of an algebraic number field" must be using terminology in a different way.)

Comment: @abx The link you give is not a full answer to the original question

Comment: Does it mean that the problem is open?? Do we have a formula for all units or not? I have not got that point yet.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of  [The group of all units of integral cyclotomic ring](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427328/the-group-of-all-units-of-integral-cyclotomic-ring)